# Importing JS package in Angular makes app to not render

Tags: angular, debugging, package, citation-js

I have come across some strange behaviour by importing a package into my Angular project. I have imported the following package into my project: [@citation-js/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@citation-js/core). If I attempt to use it in a component, the app is unable to render the page, showing the loading circle (image below). No error is displayed and I am at a lost. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

I have not done anything else, then the following:

Command to install package

```
npm install @citation-js/core --save
```

Line that causes the page to not render

```
import { Cite } from "@citation-js/core";    
let json = await Cite.inputAsync("10.5281/zenodo.1005176");
```

[What the page displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovdlf.png)

Edit: Adding await to Cite.inputAsync

Answer (score 1):

When using the package `@citation-js/core` the function `Cite.inputAsync` does not exist. In addition, the DOI plugin is not registered. You could instead use the package `citation-js` where the function does exist and the DOI plugin is automatically included, but that package is deprecated, quoting the README:

> This repository contains the npm package citation-js that wraps [@citation-js/core and certain plugins] for backwards compatibility.

To get the same function from `@citation-js/core` you can do the following:

```js
const { plugins } = require("@citation-js/core");
require("@citation-js/plugin-doi");

let json = plugins.input.chainAsync("10.5281/zenodo.1005176");
```

Note that this requires an additional dependency, `@citation-js/plugin-doi`.

Answer (score 0):

`inputAsync` is returning a Promise, so you need to wait for the Promise to be settled:

```
let json = await Cite.inputAsync("10.5281/zenodo.1005176");
```

Comment: yeah, I tried it both ways. same problem. I also tried the non async version, and the same problem occurs.